# MySQL SELECT in a large table faster with indexed INT or indexed TIMESTAMP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a `MyISAM` log table with Unix timestamp values. I will have various `SELECT` statements every once in while using a "from" date to "to" date and the table will grow quite large.

I don't know which would be the fastest between an Indexed INT or Indexed `TIMESTAMP` (they have the same storage space I believe).

I checked on Stackoverflow already but the answers are somewhat vague, from new members or they say one or the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It shouldn't make a difference. Timestamps are represented internally as integers, so comparing and indexing them will be essentially the same.

Comment: Nit: Even if it were on (an applicable) char column, it'd still be an index .. indexes [can] reduce complexity so should share similar bounds. I guess I'm pointing this out, to hedge against more "premature optimization" although this answer is good.

Comment: Thanks heaps!! I needed a simple direct an sure answer like this!

Comment: For everybody else reading this, I chose timestamp and I think it might have been a mistake as I just need to compare timestamps without needing any of the fancy date methods. Now I have to add UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), NOW() and others in my queries instead of just timestamp >= 1303634665. So think about it beforehand!